# Thin film interference equation confusion

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

For thin film interferences, why is that when you have two phase changes, the equations you use for constructive and destructive interferences are switched?

Answer (score 0):

In the first phase change, you get a phase difference of,  $$Δϕ=π$$ and so you get destructive interference. When you get the second phase change, you get another additional phase difference $$Δϕ=π$$ which is the same as no phase difference, or $$Δϕ=0$$

In other words, you will find that the two waves emerge in phase. This means you get constructive interference.